# Object Oriented Programming Involving Arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, methods, overloading

I'm so lost with this problem and I don't even know how to get to the end point. I can't even get my array to work. Can someone help me out?

> Problem #73-Write a method with a void return value that sets to 0 all
>   the elements of the  even numbered rows and sets to 1 all the elements
>   in the odd numbered rows of a 2-dimensional array of ints.   Include
>   the code to test your method.

```
public class EvenOdd
{



   /*public EvenOdd(int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns)
   {
  oddOrEven = new int [numberOfRows][numberOfColumns]; 
  }//end arrayEvenOdd
*/
   public static void main (String []args)
{
  int [][] oddOrEven = { {1,2,3} , {1,3,5} };

  for (int i = 0; i < oddOrEven.length; i++)
  {
  if (oddOrEven[i] % 2 == 0)
  {
     for(int j = 0; j < oddOrEven[i].length; j++)
     {
        oddOrEven[i][j] = 0;

     }//end loop
     System.out.print(oddOrEven[i]);
  }//end set loop

  else 
  {
     for(int j = 0; j < oddOrEven[i].length; j++)
     {
        oddOrEven[i][j] = 1;
     }
     System.out.print(oddOrEven[i]);  
  }
  }
  }
}//end class
```

Comment: For starters, I would do a Command + Shift + A and select "Reformat Code." Paste the new result here, it will be much more organized

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  What does "can't get to work" mean?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Can you paste the result you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
if (oddOrEven[i] % 2 == 0)
```

with

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: @studentneedshelp If the answer was helpful and it solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.